# realtime volume from media recorder

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, mediarecorder, web-mediarecorder

In
https://codepen.io/Sambego/pen/ZBPbbR
it provides a way to record video

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: true // We are only interested in the audio
    }).then(stream => {
        // Create a new MediaRecorder instance, and provide the audio-stream.
        recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
```

How to get real time sound volume so that I can put a volume indicator when the user is recording?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the word `sound volume` refers to peak level of the audio stream, and you want to build a peak meter.

You may want to use [`AnalyserNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode) to do this, which is part of [`AudioContext`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext) API. With an analyser node, you can get audio waveform data (and spectrum data too!), from any audio input. Here is a simple example:

```js
// Create an audio context and connect the stream source to an analyzer node
const context = new AudioContext();
const source = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
const analyzer = context.createAnalyser();
source.connect(analyzer);

// The array we will put sound wave data in
const array = new Uint8Array(analyzer.fftSize);

function getPeakLevel() {
    analyzer.getByteTimeDomainData(array);
    return array.reduce((max, current) => Math.max(max, Math.abs(current - 127)), 0) / 128;
}
```

The code above goes live here: https://codepen.io/zhangbenber/pen/eYQJWwd?editors=0010

Some notice:

- An audio context may suspend by default according to the browser's [autoplay policy](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/). You may need to call `context.resume()` **after** user actions.
- Peak level meter is only useful when you want to check whether the wave data goes out of range. If you want to represent the actual "volume", an [RMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square) meter may be more helpful.